# opencv moments within circular area

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mask

Is it possible to calculate moments within a circular region of interest? Lets say if the image is a square and your region of interest is a circle within that image. usually you can mask to get only that circular region to find its mean or std dev. Is it possible to apply similar mask while calculating moments?

Comment: Why don't you find contours for that masked region & find the moments?

Comment: Wouldn't that give the moments of that contour and not based on the structures within that contour?